# ¿Cómo convertir el formato de una cadena de input type="tel" en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Digamos que tengo la siguiente cadena 
8675203695 
Pero me gustaria que en el input se convirtiera al siguiente formato
(867) 520-3695

¿De qué manera lo lograría en javascript?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Bienvenido SG199, que has intentado?? Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, y para ayudarte debemos partir de algo... Seria bueno que nos muestres tu código para que tu también nos ayudes a nosotros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola un gusto en saludarte.

Hay una solución con una libreria basada en javascript en conjunto con Jquery que se llama inputmask, te sirve para varias cosas entre ellas dar formato a un campo input para teléfono.

te dejo el link, donde encontraras muchos ejemplos inluyendo la instalación y su uso:
[inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)
Su uso es muy basico:
proporcionas un id a tu campo input y el inputmask se encarga del resto, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"}); 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" />
```

Al escribir en el campo te lo convierte automaticamente a la mascara que le asignes.

Espero haberte ayudado, suerte!